# Merge Query In sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing Merge Query in sql and if any changes in data based on id am updating the same and inserting new data if any.
I am writing below query

```
    insert into
     DBNAME.TARGET_TABLE (COL1, ID, ID2)
    select
    COL1,
    ID,
    ID2
   from
   (
   MERGE INTO DBNAME.TARGET_TABLE AS TARGET USING (
  select
    COL1,
    ID,
    ID2
  from
    DBNAME.SOURCE_TABLE
) AS source (
COL1, ID1, ID2
) ON (
TARGET.ID = source.ID
) 
WHEN MATCHED
and (
  TARGET.ID2 <> source.ID2
  OR 
  TARGET.COL1 <> source.COL1
) 
THEN
UPDATE
SET
  TARGET.COL1 = source.COL1,
  TARGET.ID2 = source.ID2 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (COL1, ID, ID2)
VALUES
  (
    source.COL1,
    source.ID,
    source.ID2
  )
  );
```

But I am getting below error message.

```
     You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'INTO DBNAME.TARGET_TABLE AS TARGET USING 
    ( select COL1, ID' at line 9
```

Can Someone Guide me what is the issue here?

Comment: Error doesn't sound like Oracle; which database do you use? Remove tag that doesn't fit.

Comment: Could you please remove this (
COL1, ID1, ID2
)   from your query

Comment: MERGE inserts or updates tables, you cannot select from it

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code looks strange.

Comment: Could you replace ID by [ID] ?